# Six, six to find the one - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> To start at number seventeen
>   One does rise so prominently
>   With thirty eight now in between
>   And fifty five completely
>   Six, six to find the one
>   Six, six but found in three
>   Six, six and follows six
>   Five, but only count one

**Who am I?**

EDIT: Not a mathematical riddle

Adding an extra verse to give a stronger hint towards the solution:

> Oh of my name, I'm number eight
>   For I'm a part of history
>   My fame you cannot overstate
>   Nor can you my adultery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The extra verse seems to suggest that the answer might be

> King Henry VIII

and this certainly seems to be correct, but some details remain hazy.

So, as cleverly suggested by Marius in the comments, the numbers in stanza one, at least, are counting years rather than, e.g., monarchs. So, let's see.

To start at number seventeen
One does rise so prominently

> Henry VIII became king at age 17.

With thirty eight now in between
And fifty five completely

> 38 years after that he died at age 55.

That all seems straightforward enough. The second stanza has given me much grief and continues to do so. All those sixes of course suggest

> his wives

but I can't make everything line up.

Six, six to find the one

> The six wives he married to get one legitimate male heir? (The questioner confirms this, despite my doubtfulness on the grounds that he only needed three wives for that.)

Six, six but found in three

> As gtwebb suggests in comments, this may simply be because "the one" was born to H8's *third* wife. One of the sixes here (both?) may refer not to wives but to the fact that he became Edward the *Sixth*.

Six, six and follows six

> Might possibly be counting daughters, but to get enough we would need to include stillborn ones contrary to what seems to have been done with the sons. (But they did "follow six" in the sense of ascending the throne later than his son Edward VI.)
>  OP Edit: Edward VI succeeds Henry VIII

Five, but only count one

> Most likely refers to his sons; presumably the "one" is the single surviving legitimate son, Edward. Now, why five? He had a bunch of stillborn sons, but too many for the count to be five. If we only count the ones who lived beyond infancy, then we have Edward (legitimate) plus Henry FitzRoy (acknowledged illegitimate) plus, er, three of { Henry Carey, John Perrot, Thomas Stukeley, Richard Edwardes }?

Or

> perhaps the five are his acknowledged liveborn children. One legitimate son, Edward. (The one we are to count.) Two legitimate girls, Mary and Elizabeth. One acknowledged illegitimate son, Henry FitzRoy. And one other Henry who died in infancy.
>  OP Edit: References number of illegitimate sons Henry VIII allegedly had, only acknowledging one of them.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. And I think you can go through the details and see how they fit. I can give you a push in the right direction. The first 2 lines are about his age. Something happened at 17. The next 2 lines are also age related.

Comment: ah, *years*, that makes some sense.

Comment: The second verse is probably about jvirf(rot13)

Comment: And lines 5 to 8 (or at least some of them) might have something to do with his love life.

Comment: Yes, all the sixes make it look like that, which is one reason I thought it was probably him in the first place. The first verse is all obvious enough given that the numbers count years, but I am still trying to get my head around the second.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan. OK one last hint about lines 2, 3, 4 :). 2 something happened at  the age of 17. 3 and 4: $17 + 38 = 55$. I would include a wikipedia link here, but then that would spoil it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're still giving me hints for stanza 1, which was all obvious as soon as you mentioned age. It's stanza 2 I'm confused by.

Comment: Line 12 is a hint for line 8. Lines 5-7 are somewhat related to your interpretation to line 5, of which the first sentence is correct!

Comment: Yeah, I think I've got line 8 (without hints, as it happened) and am glad my guess for 5 was right. Still hazy on 6-7...

Comment: I suppose I should count the obvious other thing given my interpretation of line 8.

Comment: ... Nope, only four definite ones. Two doubtful but if we count them then we probably need to add at least one more to the "five".

Comment: Line 6: What is three, and why is that significant given the previous line? Line 7: (Line 6 will give you this answer) Line 8 is slightly off, but the nature of Henry Fitzroys birth is the right direction...

Comment: I think you answer line six with your answer on live 5...  Found in 3(rd)

Comment: gtwebb: That's a clever idea, and probably right.

Comment: Line 5 = Looking for one heir to the throne. Line 6 = ended up with three heirs, a king and two queens?

Comment: Ali: I think the three is because it was H8's third wife who bore the child who became Edward VI.

Comment: I can confirm that. Line 7 is the succession of Henry VIII by Edward VI. Line 8 are the number of alleged illegitimate 'sons' of Henry VIII, of which only Henry Fitzroy was acknowledged. (Henry had a strong desire to bare a son which is why the riddle was focused on his sons). Very difficult riddle, so you and the others have done an excellent job in working it out.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan. Sorry for pushing it with the hints for stanza 1. I misunderstood your struggle.

Comment: No problem. It would have taken me ages to think of years for stanza 1 (if I ever did) without your prodding, so I think you had every right to push as you pleased :-).

Comment: @hypern, I'm still not sure I quite understand line 7, but never mind. (Is "follows six" an inversion as in "cometh the hour, cometh the man" -- thus meaning "six follows"?)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It is meant to have the meaning 'and (what) follows (is) six'. Yes, it is an inversion.

Comment: Also, the rhyme has a similar structure to Greensleaves which is inaccurately credited to Henry VIII

Comment: Greensleeves: How did I manage not to notice that??